# Code igniter page not found error - Object not found 404

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have tried to create a e-commerce site using codeigniter by following a [tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-build-a-shopping-cart-using-codeigniter-and-jquery--net-8187)

The index page comes correctly, but if I click the `add` button I see the following in the console part of Firebug:

> Object not found!
>   The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404
>   localhost
>   Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4

Please give me some solution

Comment: what is your url ? is htacess enable ? htacess file is in folder ?

Comment: also check AllowOverride none make it AllowOverride All in httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable mod_rewrite in your apache.
2. Set your route properly
3. Configure `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

site you use the helper url, I advise you to use the site_url () function, sometimes it's not about .htaccess files. try in your address bar to put in the middle of your url to put index.php like:

**localhost / folde / index.php / controller / method**

if it gives a wanted result then use site_url () instead of base_url () which gives it a path by hometizing the index.php

Answer (score -1):

in tutplus tutorial, it is said `base_url()` is defined automatically. You could edit `config.php` and set `$config['base_url'] = "hhtp://localhost/{your_root_folder}/index.php/"` . it worked for me. I though it doesnot remove `index.php` from showing